# Running integration tests remotely with maven

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

How can I run integration tests on an environment other than the one I'm building (running maven) from? I suppose I should use the failsafe plugin, but how would it find the artifact remotely, run the tests and return results?

Specifically: I want to run my tests on a controlled environment, a docker container, regardless of building from the build server or a dev machine.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin